# HQL createQuery throws NullPointerException when create new object in query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to create new object from the result set of HQL query but it is throwing NullPointerException at `session.createQuery()`

Could someone please show me any flaw in the query that I created?

The idea is to return the `type/area/reason` along with their `count` and then create new `CasesOverview` object with these values.

```
        StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder("SELECT NEW CasesOverviewDTO(:filterColumnString, Math.toIntExact(count(c.id)), :filter) ");
        hql.append("FROM Case AS c ");
        hql.append("where c.site.id = :siteId and c.status ");
        if(isOpen) {
            hql.append("!= :close and createdDate > :startDate and createdDate < :endDate ");
        } else {
            hql.append("= :close and closedDate > :startDate and closedDate < :endDate ");
        }
        hql.append("group by :filterColumn");

        Query query = exeQuery(hql.toString());
        switch(filter) {
            case TYPE:
                query.setParameter("filterColumnString", "c.area.toString()");
                query.setParameter("filterColumn", "c.area");
                break;
            case CASE_TYPE:
                query.setParameter("filterColumnString", "c.type.toString()");
                query.setParameter("filterColumn", "c.type");
                break;
            case RESOLUTION:
                query.setParameter("filterColumnString", "c.reason.toString()");
                query.setParameter("filterColumn", "c.reason");
                break;
        }
        query.setParameter("filter", filter);
        query.setParameter("siteId", siteId);
        query.setParameter("close", "CLOSED");
        query.setParameter("startDate", startDate);
        query.setParameter("endDate", endDate);
```

In the `createQuery` method, error is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.formatMissingContructorExceptionMessage(ConstructorNode.java:201)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:193)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:158)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processConstructor(HqlSqlWalker.java:1095)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2328)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2194)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1476)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:573)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
at com.essensys.bluefin.dao.hibernate.HibernateGenericDao.exeQuery(HibernateGenericDao.java:411)
```

Comment: Your `exeQuery(hql.toString())` method is returning `null`.

Comment: @SudhirOjha yes, inside method `exeQuery()` hibernate `createQuery()` is called inside a `try-catch` block, which throwing NullPointerException as well

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace it looks like there's no constructor that would satisfy your `CasesOverviewDTO(:filterColumnString, Math.toIntExact(count(c.id))`, or if there is, it's not in the same package as the class the hql query is being created in, and therefore needs to be fully qualified (add the package name like `new com.some.package.CasesOverviewDTO(args)`). Can you please also post your `CasesOverviewDTO` ?

Comment: In the case the constructor is not valid, it will throw `inappropriate constructor for CasesOverviewDTO' which I did face before. I have the package name in my code, which is omitted here. The third paramater of `CasesOverviewDTO constructor` is another object, do I need to add the package name for it too?